# Virtual Machine organization for Windows 2012 VDI & DB Server?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, vdi

I have a single `Windows 2012` Server and trying to configure it for **2** independent purposes:

- **(1)** DB Server `MSSQL-2012`
- **(2)** `VDI` for about 5 clients.

I understand more or less how everything works but I'm little uncertain how the VM's should be nested into a single server. **Should the `Base Server` manage the VDI Pools OR should a separate VM be created to manage VDI??**

1. Base Install -- Windows 2012 Server with Hyper-V Role Enabled

   1. (VM) - Windows 2012 Server with MSSQL
   2. (VM) - Windows 2012 Server to Manage VDI Pool

      - (VM) Client VDI
      - (VM) Client VDI
      - (VM) Client VDI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is review Microsoft's LAB setups for various (and clearly defined) VDI scenarios. [VDI QuickStart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831585.aspx)